# How to vectorize processing entire row of DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas `DataFrame` as follows:

| id | name | wand core |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Harry | Phoenix Feather |
| 456 | Hermione | Dragon Heartstring |
| 678 | Ron | Unicorn hair |

**The above `DataFrame` has tens of millions of rows**

What I need to do is for every row of the `DataFrame`:

- Do some normalization i.e extract `entities` from the row. For example, `name` column is mapped to a `Wizard` class which has a `name` as an attribute (`Wizard(name="Harry")`) and `wand core` column is mapped to `Wand` class which also has a `name` attribute (`Wand(name="Unicorn hair")`)
- Return these extracted entities. Currently I am returning it as a list.
- Eventually, I am saving these entities in a CSV file and uploading to S3 for further processing.

My current implementation is as follows:

```
def process(record, final_list):
   # Convert record to dict
   # Extract entities
   # Add entities to final_list


if __name__ == '__main__':
    df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
    final_list = []
    df.apply(lambda record: process(record, final_list),axis=1)
    # Post processing on `final_list`
```

The above implementation is painfully slow. The `apply` function approach takes minutes to process a million rows.

I am very new to `DataFrames` and `Pandas`. I am sure there has to be a better approach to do this. So far, I am trying to optimize this code by trying to `vectorize` the `process` function but have hit a wall.

**EDIT 1**
Following is more details regarding `process` and relevant functions

```
def process(record, final_list):
    record_dict = record.to_dict()
    # use pydantic to validate schema
    source_schema_model = RecordClass(**record_dict)
    extracted_entities = extract_entities(source_schema_model)
    final_list.extend(extracted_entities)

def extracted_entities(source_schema_model)
    result = []
    wizard = Wizard(name=source_schema_model.name)
    wand = Wand(name=source_schema_model.name)
    result.append(wizard)
    result.append(wand)
    return result
```

Comment: You might be better off using `dask` or `pyspark` if you are looking for improvements with regards to runtime.

Comment: maybe provide the process() code , so it ca be rewritten

Comment: @eshirvana thank you for your comment, I have added the details you requested

Comment: Wizard and Wand are regular python classes. You can think of them as dataclasses

Comment: @KaranAshar hmm... then you have to rewrite those classes that can work with DataSeries.